# Search controls in a FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, search, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `FlowLayoutPanel` in my Windows Forms Application, which I use for storing movie fanarts and titles, now what I am looking for is a method to search for existing items in the `FlowLayoutPanel`. This is my GUI:

[image: GUI Screenshot]

In the `Search movies...` box, I want the `TextChanged` event to show only movies **with** the movie labels related to the search input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (Control c in myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls)
{
    if (!c.Property.Text.ToLower().Contains(searchBox.Text.ToLower()))
    {
        myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Remove(c);
    }
}
```

This will loop through the children of the panel - you can check some property against the search term and remove the child if it doesn't contain the search term.

EDIT: Based on your comment, it looks like you are getting matches only on your labels, so your pictures are going away.  The way that I would approach that is to create a UserControl that holds both the image and a label (Right-click your project - Add - UserControl - give it a name).  Use the designer to add a PictureBox and a Label (or whatever controls you are already using).  Your code behind for the UserControl would look something like this:

```
public partial class Movie : UserControl
{
    public string Title { get; set; } // for easy matching

    public Movie()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Movie(Image thumbnail, string title) // use this constructor to make your movie tiles
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Image = thumbnail;
        label1.Text = title;
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

For each movie, you can create an instance of your new custom UserControl by passing in the thumbnail image and the title and then add the entire UserControl to your FlowLayoutPanel.  Now you can keep or remove the entire UserControl depending on whether the Title property matches.  Your foreach loop changes to this:

```
foreach (Control c in flp.Controls)
{
    // Check if the control is one of your custom UserControls:
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(Movie))
    {
        // since it is a "Movie", it is safe to cast it:
        Movie movie = (Movie)c;
        if (!movie.Title.ToLower().Contains(searchBox.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            flp.Controls.Remove(c); // remove or keep both the image and text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! The text part works for me, now it lets me see this when I search for a movie: [link](http://imgur.com/download/zQqciyr) .

Comment: But I still need my movie thumbnails to be shown up when searching for a movie. I think that that isn't possible...

Comment: @KeesvanV. Everything is possible!  I have revised my answer with some additional suggestions that should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Hello;

```
            foreach (Control item in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            {
                if (item is Button)
                {
                    item.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("You lost loser!");
```

It is working.Check it out!;
#button #flowlayout #enable