# How to search for control in flowlayout based on the label text inside the panel?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello everyone I'm trying to search for control in flowlayoutpanel by taking input from textBox text and determine if that input is equal to the panel control label text, but when I typed in input on the textBox nothing happened.

This is how the panel look like

[image: generated panel]

The created panel consists of several control: Label, Picturebox, Button, 2 labels. And i want to keep all of the controls as well when the user searched for the panel based on the label text.

This is how the panel (and labels) was created:

```
                            int top = 275;
                            int h_p = 100;
                            var panelTxt = new Guna2Panel() {
                                Name = panName + itemCurr,
                                Width = 240,
                                Height = 262,
                                BorderRadius = 8,
                                FillColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#121212"),
                                BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                                Location = new Point(600, top)
                            };

                            top += h_p;
                            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(panelTxt);
                            var mainPanelTxt = ((Guna2Panel)flowLayoutPanel1.Controls[panName + itemCurr]);

                            var textboxPic = new Guna2PictureBox();
                            mainPanelTxt.Controls.Add(textboxPic);
                            textboxPic.Name = "TxtBox" + itemCurr;
                            textboxPic.Width = 240;
                            textboxPic.Height = 164;
                            textboxPic.BorderRadius = 8;
                            textboxPic.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.CenterImage;
                            textboxPic.Enabled = true;
                            textboxPic.Visible = true;

                            Label titleLab = new Label();
                            mainPanelTxt.Controls.Add(titleLab);
                            titleLab.Name = "LabVidUp" + itemCurr;
                            titleLab.Font = new Font("Segoe UI Semibold", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                            titleLab.ForeColor = Color.Gainsboro;
                            titleLab.Visible = true;
                            titleLab.Enabled = true;
                            titleLab.Location = new Point(12, 182);
                            titleLab.Width = 220;
                            titleLab.Height = 30;
                            titleLab.Text = getName;

                            titlePanelSearch = titleLab;

                            Guna2Button remButTxt = new Guna2Button();
                            mainPanelTxt.Controls.Add(remButTxt);
                            remButTxt.Name = "RemTxtBut" + itemCurr;
                            remButTxt.Width = 39;
                            remButTxt.Height = 35;
                            remButTxt.FillColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#4713BF");
                            remButTxt.BorderRadius = 6;
                            remButTxt.BorderThickness = 1;
                            remButTxt.BorderColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#232323");
                            remButTxt.Image = FlowSERVER1.Properties.Resources.icons8_garbage_66;
                            remButTxt.Visible = true;
                            remButTxt.Location = new Point(189, 218);
                            remButTxt.BringToFront();
```

I tried to loop through the controls in flowlayoutpanel and tried to search for `titleLab` label inside the created panel which what I'll use to search for the panel.

This is the textBox input:

```
private void guna2TextBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
         

        foreach(Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls) {
            if(c.GetType() == typeof(Label)) {
                Label defineLabel = (Label)c;
                if(!defineLabel.Text.ToLower().Contains(guna2TextBox5.Text.ToLower())) {
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Remove(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I type in 'Untitled' on the textBox for testing but nothings happened the panel just stays how it was before I typed anything in while I was expecting for panel with label text 'Untitled' to show up and remove the other panels with label that does not equal to the textBox input.

Refer links:

[Search controls in a FlowLayoutPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050302/search-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel)

[how can i search Controls in flow Layout panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908326/how-can-i-search-controls-in-flow-layout-panel)

Comment: You are looping the FLP controls only, the panels. You need inner loop to get the `c.Controls` collections where the labels belong. If the panels also contain containers with children, then you need a _recursive_ routine to loop the _tree_.

Comment: @dr.null `You need inner loop to get the c.Controls collections where the labels belong` That's exactly where I'm stuck at right now I don't know how to implement that do you have example code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419159/how-to-get-all-child-controls-of-a-windows-forms-form-of-a-specific-type-button

Comment: Hans and Null while I understand that the code in the post is failing for "not" [iterating the  control tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62174482/5438626) the thing I _don't_ get is why the idea of iterating every control in every panel is being entertained as a good way to fulfill on the actual intent of filtering the flow layout panel. It's not!

Comment: @IVSoftware ah, whatever you say. Calm down, slow down, read carefully, understand the problem, then suggest a solution if you have one. Maybe your solution is right and we are wrong. Nothing wrong with that. Just wait for the OP to tell. [Btw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14171304/dr-null?tab=votes&sort=downvote). RELAX :)

Comment: Oh I'm calm - just me and the elephant in the room over here having a smoke. Just saying this could be considered an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) where X is the OP's stated goal to "search[...] for the panel based on the label [inside the panel] text". Recursing the control tree means 5 ops for each panel just to cull out the Labels and at least one to identify the `titleLab` to reach the goal of comparing `titleLab.Text` to the search term in `guna2TextBox5.Text`. I'm just pointing out that 7 ops is more than 1, especially at scale.

Answer (score 0):

There are three potential problems with your code for `guna2TextBox5_TextChanged1`:

1. This method is looking for `Label` controls in the `Controls` collection of `flowLayoutPanel1` that are actually in the `Controls` collection of the `Guna2Panel`. As others have pointed out, interating the control tree of flow layout panel *will* find these labels, but not in a manner that is in any way efficient in terms of a search.
2. Your post says you want **"to search for `titleLab` label"** specifically. The current code yields a positive match if "any" `Label` meets the criteria.
3. Your method is calling `Remove(c)`. But you say that **"i want to keep all of the controls"** and to do that you would want to set the `Visible` property of the `Guna2Panel` to `false` instead. The UI strongly implies that clicking on  is how user can permanently `Remove` one of the panels and delete the image file.

One way to address all of these issues is to create a `UserControl` that would be configured to match the image you posted of **"how the panel look like"**. This control could expose a public property `TitleLabelText` that will make filtering much more efficient.

---

[image: user control]

```
public partial class Guna2Panel : UserControl
{
    public Guna2Panel() => InitializeComponent();

    private FileInfo _fileInfo;
    public string FullPath
    {
        get => _fileInfo.FullName;
        set
        {
            _fileInfo = new FileInfo(value);
            Refresh();
        }
    }
    public string TitleLabelText => _fileInfo.Name;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => _fileInfo.LastWriteTime;
        set 
        {
            _fileInfo.LastWriteTime = value;
            Refresh();
        }
    }
    public new void Refresh() 
    {
        titleLab.Text = _fileInfo.Name;
        labelDate.Text = _fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToShortDateString();
        var img =  Image.FromFile(FullPath);
        textboxPic.Image = img;
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/23400751/5438626
        if (Array.IndexOf(img.PropertyIdList, 274) > -1)
        {
            var orientation = (int)img.GetPropertyItem(274).Value[0];
            switch (orientation)
            {
                case 1: break;
                case 3: img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);   break;
                case 4: img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipX); break;
                case 5: img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipX); break;
                case 6: img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone); break;
                case 7: img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipX); break;
                case 8: img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipNone); break;
            }
            // This EXIF data is now invalid and should be removed.
            img.RemovePropertyItem(274);
        }
        base.Refresh();
    }
}
```

---

**Search**

This makes a more efficient search in the main form to filter the `FlowLayoutPanel` for matches where `TitleLabelText` contains `guna2TextBox5.Text`. It also meets the requirement **"to keep all of the controls"** even those that are not currently visible.

[image: search]

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        guna2TextBox5.TextChanged += guna2TextBox5_TextChanged;
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        string folder = Path.Combine(
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
            "stackoverflow",
            typeof(MainForm).Assembly.GetName().Name,
            "Images");
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        foreach (var fullPath in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
        {
            flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(new Guna2Panel
            {
                FullPath = fullPath,
                Margin = new Padding(5),
            });
        }
    }

    private void guna2TextBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(guna2TextBox5.Text))
        {
            foreach (var userControl in flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Guna2Panel>())
            {
                userControl.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var userControl in flowLayoutPanel.Controls.OfType<Guna2Panel>())
            {
                userControl.Visible = userControl.TitleLabelText.Contains(guna2TextBox5.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/user-control-search.git) demo project.